# Typescript Comments in bundled js-file

Tags: javascript, typescript

is there a way to add an important comment to the top of the bundled js-file in typescript.

i would like to add automaitcally a comment with the Version-information to the top of the js-file everytime it gets "compiled".

like:

```
/*!
v 1.0.1.0
Git:...
License: MIT
...
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a set of "header" and "footer" tools. I'm using [gulp-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header) and [gulp-footer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-footer). I beleive similar tools are existing for other build tools.

Comment: thanks! i will have a look at these tools. Never used gulp before.